# Error caused by use of CASE in WHERE Clause

Tags: sql, oracle

Table A :

| ID | NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | High |
| 9 | Low |
| 10 | High |
| 10 | High |
| 10 | High |
| 8 | Med |
| 9 | Low |
| 8 | Med |

I have written something like

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_A 
where id = case when name like '%High%' then max(id)-1 
                else max(id) end;
```

But with above query I am getting error :

```
ORA-00934: group function is not allowed here
```

I don't know why it doesn't work, please somebody help me Thanks in advance!

Output should be :

| ID | NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 9 | Low |
| 9 | Low |

Comment: It's generally better to use AND/OR instead of case expressions in the WHERE clause.

Comment: Which result do you expect? Could you explain it in plain English?

Comment: Please include the output you want based on this table.

Comment: General advice: Aggregate function conditions should be put in a HAVING clause (instead of WHERE.) However, that's not the solution in this specific case.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. Are you trying to show the 'High' row only when it happens to have the second highest ID in the table and show the row with the highest ID otherwise? Or what else?

Comment: If the max(id) has high as Name then I want to go to next max(id) or max(id)-1 else I want to take max(id). I hope this helps in understanding the output I expect :)

Comment: I have included the output I'm expecting from the query, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From Oracle 12, you can use something like:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   TABLE_A
ORDER BY
       id - CASE WHEN name LIKE '%High%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END DESC
FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_a (ID, NAME) AS
SELECT 10, 'High' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  9, 'Low'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  8, 'Low'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  7, 'Low'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  6, 'High' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | ID | NAME |
> | --- | --- |
> | 9 | Low |
> | 10 | High |

---

> I don't know why it doesn't work

As the error states:

```
ORA-00934: group function is not allowed here
```

Aggregation functions are not allowed in the `WHERE` clause. You would need to put it into either the `SELECT` or a `HAVING` clause but then you would get more errors as you do not include a `GROUP BY` clause and are also selecting columns that are not aggregated.

You could use an analytic function `MAX(id) OVER ()` but that still is not allowed in the `WHERE` clause. Instead, you would need something like:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT a.*,
         MAX(id - CASE WHEN name LIKE '%High%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER ()
           AS max_id
  FROM   TABLE_A a
)
WHERE  max_id = id - CASE WHEN name LIKE '%High%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;
```

---

From your comment:

> If the max(id) has high as Name then I want to go to next max(id) or max(id)-1 else I want to take max(id).

You can use the `ROW_NUMBER` analytic function:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT a.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id DESC) AS rn
  FROM   TABLE_A a
)
WHERE  (rn = 1 AND name NOT LIKE '%High%')
OR     rn = 2
FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY;
```

Which outputs:

> | ID | NAME | RN |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 9 | Low | 2 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=e26577615d38a1fcd9792935871e09dc)*